# If I want to use the logger using dependency injection (no static), how do I register the bean on spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection

What would be a good way to create a bean to use the logger in a controller via dependency injection, like the code below?

```
@RestController
class SecondController(
    private val logger: Logger,
) {

    @GetMapping("/logger")
    fun logger() {
        logger.info("id $id")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What is the benefit.

Comment: While loggers may *seem* a good candidate for being injected at first, they usually aren't. Loggers are such a core thing that you want them to work even if DI breaks for some reason. And you often want them available in places DI can't (easily) reach. And there's no real benefit: You don't care about them during testing, so it's not a real problem if they are statically initialized.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend it, what is the gain over adding `@Autowired` to writing `Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());`.

That being said you can write an `@Bean` method for a prototype scoped bean and use the [`InjectionPoint`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InjectionPoint.html) to obtain the information about the class etc. and use that to create a `Logger`.

```java
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Logger logger(InjectionPoint ip) {
  return LoggerFactory.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
}
```

This will allow a dynamic (sort of) bean to be created for each `Logger` that is `@Autowired`.

Comment: If this works please accept this answer as the one that solved it.